# Subprocess call python script not producing Jasper Report but cmd execution does

Tags: python, jasper-reports, subprocess

When I run this at command line it generates my  Jasper report correctly:

```
jasperstarter pr "C:\users\ant\jaspersoftworkspace\myreports\carereport.jrxml" -f pdf -t postgres -H localhost -n template_postgis_20 -u postgres -p postgres -P SiteID=123
```

However, if I then try to run it through python with the following code the report doesn't get created. Am I messing up the syntax somewhere?

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import call

subprocess.call(["cmd","/C","jasperstarter","pr","""C:\users\ant\jaspersoftworkspace\myreports\carereport.jrxml""","-f","pdf",
"-t","postgres","-H","localhost","-n","template_postgis_20","-u","postgres","-p","postgres",
"-P","SiteID=123"], shell=True)
```

**EDIT:**

Following the comments, I tried running this at cmd after typing python to bring up >>>:

```
jasperstarter pr "C:\users\ant\jaspersoftworkspace\myreports\carereport.jrxml" -f pdf -t postgres -H localhost -n template_postgis_20 -u postgres -p postgres -P SiteID=123
```

This time I got a syntax error at -u. I then tried reordering the parameters and the syntax error then occurred at the same character number, rather than at the -u. So is there a maximum line length when entering commands in python at cmd?

Answer (score 1):

`\a` is a escape sequence that is same to `\x07` (BEL). You should escape `\` or use raw string literal to make `\a` represent `\a` literally.

```
>>> '\a' # not escaped
'\x07'
>>> '\\a' # escaped
'\\a'
>>> r'\a' # raw string literal
'\\a'
```

So, replace following:

```
"""C:\users\ant\jaspersoftworkspace\myreports\carereport.jrxml"""
```

with

```
"""C:\\users\\ant\\jaspersoftworkspace\\myreports\\carereport.jrxml"""
```

or

```
r"""C:\users\ant\jaspersoftworkspace\myreports\carereport.jrxml"""
```

**UPDATE**

Try following:

```
subprocess.call(r'jasperstarter pr "C:\users\ant\jaspersoftworkspace\myreports\carereport.jrxml" -f pdf -t postgres -H localhost -n template_postgis_20 -u postgres -p postgres -P SiteID=123', shell=True)
```

Comment: hmm, tried both of your suggestions but still didn't work, could it be anything else? i'm running python 2.7 on windows server 2012. i've run similar subprocess calls countless times successfully on the same setup

Comment: nope, that's half the problem. for a while it would run instantly as if nothing happened, then i realised a typo and now it takes a couple of seconds which is what i'd expect. so it's doing something. it always says 'Script run ok', i'm using PyScripter

Comment: @user2581350, `"cmd","/C",` seems to redundant. Remove it and try again. (Of course, you should escape the path).

Comment: @user2581350, What about `subprocess.call(r'jasperstarter pr "C:\users\ant\jaspersoftworkspace\myreports\carereport.jrxml" -f pdf -t postgres -H localhost -n template_postgis_20 -u postgres -p postgres -P SiteID=123', shell=True)`?

Comment: `shell=True` seems unnecessary. Otherwise, passing the whole command as it looks like on the command line using a raw-string literal is the first thing to try. Put it into your answer, instead of the comment.

Comment: thanks, tried the update suggestion but still no joy, with or without shell=True. weird. is there an alternative to using subprocess? i'd like to keep it a python script due to other scripts i'm running

Comment: @user2581350: what happens if you copy the command inside `subprocess.call(r'the command',..)` and paste it into your console?

Comment: if i paste this: r'jasperstarter pr "C:\users\ant\jaspersoftworkspace\myreports\carereport.jrxml" -f pdf -t postgres -H localhost -n template_postgis_20 -u postgres -p postgres -P SiteID=123' it becomes 'jasperstarter pr "C:\\users\\ant\\jaspersoftworkspace\\myreports\\carereport.jrxml" -f pdf -t postgres -H localhost -n template_postgis_20 -u postgres -p postgres -P SiteID=123'

Comment: @user2581350: you should omit `r'` at the begining and `'` at end. I meant what happens if you copy-paste the command **and run it**.

Comment: if i type it straight into cmd it works. but if i type python, then run it I get a syntax error for '-u'. But that is the correct parameter, I tried -U and got the same response

Comment: i tried changing the order of the parameters, and the syntax error seems to come at the same point in the line regardless of parameter. is there a maximum line length before an error is thrown?

Comment: @user2581350: I've been only interested whether the command works in cmd. It shouldn't work in Python console (Python uses different syntax than `cmd.exe`). What happens if you try the last code example in the answer from the same directory? Note: "no joy" is not informative. What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian - sorry i'm not sure what you mean. if i run the command at console, it works fine and generates the report regardless of directory. If i type python at cmd and then run it, i get the syntax error as quoted above. if i run subprocess.call(r'the command',..) in Pyscripter, i get 'Script run OK' but no report is generated.

Comment: @user2581350: what is "the report" is it a file? Put `import subprocess; subprocess.check_call(r'...')` inside `run_jasper.py` and run it in cmd.exe using the command `python run_jasper.py`. What happens?

Comment: the report is a jasper report, carereport.jrxml. jasperstarter is a utility to automatically generate jasper reports. thanks i'll try that

Comment: executed as per your suggestion, the report is generated. Then pressing run on the same script in Pyscripter i get 'Command returned non-zero exit status 1'